# Polymertemplate instantiation time

Tags: polymer, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using [a library](https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/autosuggest/issues/8) that in its main class extends `PolymerTemplate` where I noticed that the creation of an instance of the component in the library takes about 20ms.

I've removed basically everything from that class and the corresponding .js files to end up with the simplest possible component... basically a div with no content. And still to create this mi

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Autosuggest<String> autosuggest1 = new Autosuggest<>();

long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
System.out.println("ExecutionTime: " + elapsedTime + " ms");
```

My guess now is, that it takes that long to create the dependency on `PolymerTemplate`. Is there a way to speed up this creation process? Or maybe defer it to a later stage?

I'd simply need to speed up the loading of a formular that has several of those components in it.

**Update 09/09/2021:**
I've updated the [libray in question from PolymerTemplate to LitTemplate](https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/autosuggest/pull/9). Still a bit slow, but at least future proof. In case there is a [sampler](https://github.com/hons82/vaadin_sampler) to test it as well.

Comment: How many instances of the component are you creating? 50? 100? More? Do you have them all visible at once, or can you stand to lazy-load some of them?

Comment: To clarify on the question about how many instances you're creating, the point is that the first instantiation does a bunch of preparation work that is cached so that future instantiations of the same component class should be significantly faster. For this reason, it's best to look at the median time for a warmed up-system rather than only a single invocation after a cold start.

Comment: @Leif Looks like this was cross-posted in the vcf java component.. I don't think there is any cache inside the java constructor of Autosuggest; just a bunch of nested component creations.

Comment: There is a ~50% decrease in creation time from the first to the following instantiations. The first takes something like 50/60ms. I have a form with lets say up to 50 of those components together with other form elements in a horizontal layout (simplified, because in reality there might be a mix of vert. and horiz.layouts) .. this makes lazy loading quite difficult... but if there is no way to speed the creation up, I'll need to find a way of lazy loading or pre-caching it somehow